# 2 Jpanels inside a frame. Left panel is menu with buttons. Use Buttons to switch Right Panel.

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, containers

I am trying to write a program where there are 2 panels at all times. The left panel will be a menu with buttons, while the right panel will change depending on the buttons pushed in either panel.

Right now i am stuck. when clicking the "recipeRolodexButton" nothing happends. What i want to happen is, the right panel is either removed and replaced by my panel method, or it is overwritten by another panel.

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


//Buttons
        JButton recipeRolodexButton = new JButton("Recipe Rolodex");
        JButton groceryFinanceButton = new JButton("Grocery Finance");
        JButton testButton1 = new JButton("Test Button");

        JPanel homeLeftPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel homeRightPanel = new JPanel();
        RolodexOptionsPane rop = new RolodexOptionsPane();

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
    new Window();
    }

    public Window(){

    //declarations
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dim = new Dimension();        
    dim = tk.getScreenSize();
    GridBagConstraints gbcl = new GridBagConstraints();



    //setting up the window 
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(550,300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Food Management");       
    int xPosition = ( (dim.width / 2) - this.getWidth() / 2);
    int yPosition = ( (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() / 2));
    this.setLocation(xPosition, yPosition);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setResizable(false);

        //Add Action Listeners
        recipeRolodexButton.addActionListener(this);;
        groceryFinanceButton.addActionListener(this);
        testButton1.addActionListener(this);

        //Setting up Main Panels
        homeLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        homeLeftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        homeRightPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        homeRightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // setting the Button constraints in the main Left Panel buttons 
    gbcl.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbcl.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbcl.gridy = 0;
    gbcl.gridx = 0;             
    gbcl.ipady = 4;
    gbcl.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
    homeLeftPanel.add(recipeRolodexButton,gbcl);                
    gbcl.gridy = 1;
    homeLeftPanel.add(groceryFinanceButton, gbcl);              
    gbcl.gridy = 2;
    homeLeftPanel.add(testButton1, gbcl);

    // setting up the buttons in the main right panel



    // EXECUTION!!!!!!!!!!!!
    PanelSet(homeLeftPanel,homeRightPanel);     

}

public void PanelSet(JPanel left , JPanel right){

    GridBagConstraints gbcLeft = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints gbcRight = new GridBagConstraints();

    //positioning the panels        
            gbcLeft.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbcLeft.gridx = 0;
            gbcLeft.gridy = 0;
            gbcLeft.weightx = .15;
            gbcLeft.weighty = .5;               

            gbcRight.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbcRight.gridx = 1;
            gbcRight.gridy = 0;
            gbcRight.weightx = .85;


this.add(left,gbcLeft);
this.add(right,gbcRight);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == recipeRolodexButton){
       PanelSet(recipeRolladexButton,rop);

    }

}



}
```

sorry about the spacing. When copying my code over, the indentation was lost.

Comment: `When copying my code over, the indentation was lost.` - fix your code. Either use all spaces or all tabs, but don't mix the two. Also method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Don't call you class "Window". There is an AWT class by that name which can cause confusion. Pick a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 2):

> while the right panel will change depending on the buttons pushed in either panel.

You should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for the right panel. Then when you click a button you just specify the name of the panel to be displayed and the `CardLayout` will do the rest.

The tutorial has a working example that shows how to swap panels when selecting an item from a combo box.